# Recover on Different Branch After Git Reset

Tags: git

Someone sent me an "updated" version of a data file I've been working with. I didn't realize that it was only partially updated and that I actually needed to merge their changes with what I already had before I overwrote the data I was using.

In order to recover their data, I started a new branch (`git checkout -b datafix`), reset to a commit that I knew had the original data I needed (`git reset --hard 91ecb113f`), made my changes and committed just the data file (`git add data.csv`, `git commit -m "update data"`), switched back to master and then tried to check out just the data file (`git checkout master`, `git checkout datafix data\survey_data.csv`). But it looks like my changes to other files in the repo got overwritten.

I realize now that doing a hard reset even after changing branches probably overwrote my files. Is there any way to recover my un-committed changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git reflog --all` to list all the commits in your repository including the ones that are not attached to any branch. Switch manually to the last unattached commit and merge from there.